# Laravel Live Search AJAX Eloquent Clickable Items

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I followed [this](https://allwebtuts.wordpress.com/2016/07/03/ajax-live-search/) tutorial to create a live search with AJAX and Eloquent (accessing the DB) in a laravel app. Now I'm wondering, how I can make the search results clickable, so the thing I click is entered in the input field. Somehow, just adding a click handler and then setting `.val()` to the query seems to not be working (expect I made a mistake)... PS: I'm using jQuery as well.

How could I do that? Here the code, to be precise:

blade template:

```
<div id="content">
   <input type="search" name="keyword" placeholder="Search Names" id="searchbox">
   <div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

JS in there (don't wonder, I added a little thing to wait for the user to finish typing before sending AJAX request):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
        var doneTypingInterval = 300;  //time in ms (5 seconds)

        $("#searchbox").on('keyup', function () {
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
            if ($('#searchbox').val()) {
                typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
            }
        });
    });

    //user is "finished typing," do something
    function doneTyping() {
        var key = $('#searchbox').val();

        if (key.length >= 3) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/categorysearch/' + key,
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#results").slideUp('fast');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#results").html(data);
                    $("#results").slideDown('fast');
                }
            });

   }
}
```

and php file/function processing:

```
public function Index(Request $request){
        $query = "%".$request->categorySearchTerm."%";
        $categories = Subcategory::where('name','LIKE',$query)->get();
        foreach($categories as $category){
            echo "<div id='item'>$category->name</div>";
        }
    }
```

Now how can I get what I want, so clicking on the item puts the content of the item in the input field?

Comment: `echo "<div id='item' onClick="$('#searchbox'.val('".$category->name."'));">$category->name</div>";` instead your code in foreach

Comment: looks plausible, but just one thing: in this php file (in the controller), I don't have jquery available (maybe I wasn't clear enough in my description), I just have it in the blade template. How can I do this without jQuery?

Comment: @mcklayin Just tried this: `echo "<div id='item' onClick="document.getElementById('searchbox').setAttribute('value', $category->name);">$categ‌​ory->name</div>";` but it doesn't work, saying `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'document' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the category as data attribute to get after with jQuery something like this:

```
public function Index(Request $request){
    $query = "%".$request->categorySearchTerm."%";
    $categories = Subcategory::where('name','LIKE',$query)->get();
    foreach($categories as $category){
        echo "<div id='item' data-name='$category->name'>$category->name</div>";
    }
}
```

then you can get the value and set with a function like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#item', function() {
    $('input').val($(this).data('name'));
});
```

Here the idea working: https://jsfiddle.net/yhwsy6x7/1/

Comment: Works fine, tried so much but now its that easy ;) Thanks ;)

Comment: Just one more question: Can I somehow let the search results disappear after clicking on it and its in the input? Or is this much more work?

Comment: You could remove all divs into your result div in the function which you set the value in the input.